# reproductor en javascript no adelanta canciones automaticamente

Tags: javascript

En este proyecto avance solo, leyendo códigos en internet y con algo de teoría pero esta vez me quede estancado.

Las canciones no avanzan automáticamente

```
function() {
    songValues[position].pause()
    songValues[position].currentTime = 0;
    if (position < songs.length-1) {
        position++;
        songValues[position].play()
    }
        else
            {
            position = 0;
            songValues[position].setAttribute("id", position);
            songValues[position].play()
        
   }  
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

esta es la funcion que uso para avanzar entre cancion dandole un click al boton avanzar

```
songValues[position].addEventListener("ended", nextSong)
let currentValue = 0
// un bucle que aniade uno al goFordward que recorra la playlist.
function nextSong() {
        if (position < songs.length-1) {
          position++;
        } else {
          position = 0;
        }
        songValues[position].play()
      }
```

esta es la función con la que busco que la canción avance cuando acabe. Una disculpa si es muy basico de verdad estoy dando mi mejor esfuerzo

Comment: No se que hace la funcion loadSongs. y tambien la primera funcion no hace nada, ni es posible llamarla. Normalmente cuando uno hace ese tipo de funcion uno lo asigna a una variable: var next_song=function(){/*You codes*/}; . o simplemente: function next_song(){/*You codes*/} .

Comment: Esta pregunta necesita detalles y aclaraciones.

Comment: hola ya lo corregí pero sigue saliendo lo mismo solo avanza mi cancion una vez y necesito que lo avance automaticamente

Comment: puedes chequear porfavor ahora que esta corregido?

Answer (score 0):

Con el código que se muestra, parece que solamente asignas el evento a una canción y, dado que comentas que solamente funciona una vez, diría que hay que asignarlo a todas:

En lugar de:

```
songValues[position].addEventListener("ended", nextSong)
```

Podrías hacer un ciclo que itere por todos los elementos y les asigne el evento, por ejemplo:

```
songValues.foreach(song => song.addEventListener("ended", nextSong));
```

De esta forma, la función `nextSong` va a ser invocada cuando se dé el evento `ended` de todas las canciones que están en el arreglo `songValues`.